# How to retrieve a Map values inside a field of a specific document in firestore using flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get all the Values of the map which is under "Subjects" field. And I also want to listen if any updates or changes made to those values. I actually want to add al those values and store in a variable. Can someone please tell me how can i achieve this?

Here is the structure of the collection.
[image]

This is how im adding the subjects whenever a user enters the subject name

```
onPressed: () async {
                      temp = qrdataFeed.text;
                        int index = qrdataFeed.text.indexOf('-');
                        subject = qrdataFeed.text.substring(0, index);
                        print("Subject name is $subject");
                        numberOfClasses = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('tutors')
                            .doc(uid)
                            .get()
                            .then((doc) async {
                          Map<String, dynamic> map = await doc.data();
                          if (!map.containsKey('Subjects')) {
                            await tutor_details.doc(uid).set({
                              'Subjects': {'$subject': initialValue},
                            }, SetOptions(merge: true));
                          }
                          if (doc.data()['Subjects']['$subject'] !=
                              '$subject') {
                            if (!map.containsKey('$subject')) {
                              await tutor_details.doc(uid).set({
                                'Subjects': {'$subject': initialValue}
                              }, SetOptions(merge: true));
                            }
                          }
                          var val = await doc.data()['Subjects']['$subject'];
                          return val;
                        });

                        if (!mounted) return;
                        setState(() {
                          qrData = qrdataFeed.text;
                          scanned = true;
                          print('done');
                          //if (temp != qrdataFeed.text)
                          numberOfClasses += 1;
                          print('$numberOfClasses is printed');
                        });
                        await tutor_details.doc(uid).set({
                          'Subjects': {'$subject': numberOfClasses},
                        }, SetOptions(merge: true));
                      }
                    },
```

Comment: Try going through this article. It clearly explains how you should `Stream` to achieve real time listeners. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes

Comment: @NisanthReddy Do I need to use StreamBuilder even if i just want to get the realtime details and store that in the firestore as a separate field?

Comment: You are listening to changes in firestore only to again save those changes into firestore ? Why so ?

Comment: I'm actually trying to add all the values of a map which is inside the Subjects field and then store that value to a new field.
Like for example :"TotalClasses" : xyz ,, i want to again retrieve this xyz value from other part of program to calculate the attendance percentage

Comment: Where are you adding your data in the original place ? How is your `Subjects` data getting filled first ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy i have added the snippet how I'm adding the subjects. In this code itself can i add the values without retrieving again? Please check it once.

Comment: Yes, since you are already adding here using `set` you can also set your `TotalClasses` here itself. Basically, whenever you are setting your `Subjects` update your `TotalClasses` also there itself.

Comment: But that will be set only when the particular subject is going to be added for the first time

Comment: okay, in that case, where are you updating the values of Subject after the first time

Comment: `await tutor_details.doc(uid).set({'Subjects': {'$subject': numberOfClasses},}, SetOptions(merge: true));`
at the last in the snippet i shared in the question

Comment: So you can update your `TotalClasses` from here as well. A better architecture would be to have one class at the root to handle all your transactions and to also notify any listener in your code.You  should always call this class to update and you can add listeners to this class from any widget you want. This way you will have everything firestore related in one place.

Comment: @Learn have you managed to find the solution?

Comment: @Farid Shumbar Yes i did it in the way Nisanth Reddy suggested.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. @NisanthReddy do you mind posting your advice as the answer to this question? This will help to make the solution more visible for the community.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the @NisanthReddy's solution as a Community Wiki for visibility.

A better architecture would be to have one class at the root to handle all your transactions and to also notify any listener in your code.

You should always call this class to update and you can add listeners to this class from any widget you want. This way you will have everything Firestore-related in one place.